# Caching algorithm for Node js with redis

Tags: node.js, mongodb, caching, redis

I have website application where users can upload gifs and get those.
Backend is Node js, database mongodb and use redis for caching. 
I'm caching searches with parameters.
Cache like this , after every search sorting query parameters ,checking for cache , if not find after getting from mongodb create cache.

[image]

When user uploading gif need update cache, but I expect that can be many uploads for small time and caching will lose its meaning.
Please help find good solution.

Comment: How do the parameters relate to the gifs themselves? You need that link and then you can invalidate the cache after a new gif is uploaded that will match that term. There isn't an easy answer here and your going to need to provide much more detail.

Comment: You are aware that cache invalidation is one of the two only difficult things in computering, right? :) So it can't be answered in one small answer here.